# how to implement a hit counter in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web-services, cookies, idioms, hitcounter

How, generally, would a PHP style [Hit Counter](http://justintadlock.com/web-design/counter) get implemented in JavaScript?

This PHP [example](http://justintadlock.com/web-design/counter):

```
<?php

/* counter */

//opens countlog.txt to read the number of hits
$datei = fopen("/countlog.txt","r");
$count = fgets($datei,1000);
fclose($datei);
$count=$count + 1 ;
echo "$count" ;
echo " hits" ;
echo "\n" ;

// opens countlog.txt to change new hit number
$datei = fopen("/countlog.txt","w");
fwrite($datei, $count);
fclose($datei);

?>
```

runs on the server, not in the browser like JavaScript generally does.

Comment: you mean click counter for webpage?

Comment: not sure of distinction.  by hit counter I mean visits to the page.  Not terribly concerned about unique versus repeat.

Comment: js can only count the client site, you need call api to let the server know

Comment: how about some sort of web service?  or does that not solve persistence problem?